# NodeJs & Web3 having problem with VS Code IntelliSense (autocomplete)

Tags: web3js, nodejs, visual-studio-code

I'm having issue with autocomplete of Web3 module members in the VS Code.

As can be noticed on the screen below `web3.eth.` not proposing any member of the module.

web3 module has been installed over `npm install web3`

`jsconfig.json` and `package.json` have been included - see on the screen.

Am I missing something. Works fine when `import Web3 from 'web3'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

Try this viscode extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lemon-berry.web3js-snippets

Answer (score 0):

I use this extension for web3JS auto complete https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=capaj.vscode-exports-autocomplete

it also help in autocompleting when i install any new module. It grab the functions of that module and make snippets out of those modules.